# How to normalize JSON response and convert it into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to standardize a JSON string and convert it into a dataframe. My actual data is for work and it's confidential so I can't show it here, but I think this small made-up scenario below illustrates the point I'm trying to make.

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


# doesn't work at all...
url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
response = requests.get(url)
text = response.text


# throws error
df = json_normalize(text)



# can convert to list but can't print columns
my_list=[]
my_list.append(text)
print(type(my_list))

df = json_normalize(my_list)

df.columns
print(type(df))
df
```

What I get is a dictionary wrapped inside a list. How can I normalize the JSON string and/or convert it into a standardized dataframe? My actual JSON file has a structure like this:

```
[{'id': '21201', 'name': 'SRW Utility, 4x4', 'latitude': 35.31068751, 'longitude': -80.66177891, 'headingDegrees': 161.2, 'speedMilesPerHour': 0}]
```

I am trying to extract 'id', 'latitude', 'longitude', etc, as headers, and show the data in rows below these headers.

Comment: You can just use 'pd.DataFrame(my_list)'

Comment: If I do this: data=pd.DataFrame(my_list) & data.columns...I get this: Index(['data', 'pagination'], dtype='object')

One single column named 'data' has over 100 columns packed into it: 
0  [{'id': '2120149', 'name': '31315-LD M...

I can't get the 1 column split into 100+ columns. That's the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `response.json()` instead of `response.text`:

```
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get(url)
df = pd.json_normalize(response.json())
print(df)

# Output
    timestamp  message iss_position.latitude iss_position.longitude
0  1679492418  success              -20.9276              -149.5842
```

**Note**

Using `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` is deprecated. It raises a `FutureWarning`:

> **FutureWarning**: `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` is deprecated, use `pandas.json_normalize` instead.

Comment: Thanks Corralien. But, if I run this: pd.json_normalize(response.json()), I get this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'

BAsically, I have this:

headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "authorization": "bearer_token: blah, blah, blah..."
    }
    
    
    response = requests.request("GET", fetch_url, headers=headers).json()

Comment: OK. you already converted the response as dictionary. It's not the same as your code (`test = response.text`)